# PDO_MYSQL configure failed when installing so file

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have installed php 5.4.44 and mysql 5.1.51, and I tried to install `pdo_mysql`, but when I execute the command `./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/php/bin/php-config --with-pdo-mysql=/usr/local/mysql --with-zlib-dir=/usr/lib64/`, always shows

> PDO_MYSQL configure failed, MySQL 4.1 needed.

I have tried change the version of PHP which doesn't work, where is the problem and how can I fix this?

Comment: What version of **mysql** do you have installed on the machine where you build *php*?

Comment: Most likely you need to install the appropriate -dev or -devel package for mysql on the machine you're attempting to build with. What OS are you building on (appears to be a Linux)? It is uncommon to need to compile PDO drivers, as they are typically available in OS repositories.

Comment: I build on Ubuntu14.04 and use mysql 5.1.51, and which version of -dev or -devel package for mysql should be installed? I haven't install the packages manually.

Answer (score 1):

Installation processes require the development headers along with the binaries. In this case, you are missing `libmysqlclient-dev`:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

change configure path with:--with-pdo-mysql=/path/to/mysql_config

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it